# Using an Agilent Power supply as an active load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have an Aglient power supply Model number N5747A, and I want to use its current sinking ability to become an active load.

This is to test a DC/DC converter (5VDC Output), [Gaia MGDS-35-H-C](http://www.gaia-converter.com/datasheets/hi-rel/MGDM35revC.pdf), I want to load the output of the DC/DC to 75% load.

**Requirement of Electronic Load**
I am using an active load because I need to vary the load from 1% to 100% in 15 steps. An active load will be smoother and more accurate.

According to the datasheet 75% load is around 5.25A. My idea is to hook up the Agilent power supply and set the current limit to 5.25A on the output of the DC/DC converter.

My question is, what kind of "fixed" resistance would I need, would it be just to protect the Agilent supply and DC/DC converter? I assume I would need some kind of power resistor.

The power supply will create a current loop and force the DC/DC converter to draw 75% of its maximum current. Am I correct in my understanding of this?

Below is a drawing for 100% load (7A) on the output of the DC/DC converter

[image: Quick Drawing]

Then the fixed resistance I chose was to maintain a safe operating voltage for the current sink. Example: 60V current source, to maintain 7A's of current through the loop a 4 Ohm resistor will operate the current source in the middle of its operating voltage range of around (28V - 5V )= 23V. If you chose an 8 Ohm resistor for example, then you'll be operating really close to the supply's limits (7A * 8 Ohms = 56V-5=51V). Also the fixed resistor limit in cause the supply goes to 0V (a dead short), so at least 5V/7A = 1 Ohm minimum (rounded up for safety) to put a fixed cap on the current that will flow.

Comment: What in the datasheet or manual for the N5747A makes you think it has a "current sinking ability"? I read the datasheet and I didn't see anything to suggest that. But I didn't read the manual.

Comment: Instead of the N5747A, have a look at the 6063B "electronic load".

Comment: What is the voltage on the output of your DC/DC converter? You could use a high power trimpot and an ammeter to load up the output to 5.25A - just a low tech hack but if you had one of these: http://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Ohmite/RJS35RE/?qs=qUoEFYkZCa9F2vBhZXkFtQ== and the power was within the rating of the trimpot, you could do it. You might have to adjust it if the output voltage drifts under load.

Comment: @The Photon Its a 5VDC output for the DC/DC converter, the N5747 has a constant current source capability, and constant voltage automatic crossover

Comment: Is there anything that says that it has a current *sink* capability? I.E. that it can control current when the current is going **in** to the more positive terminal?

Comment: Another source for electronic loads is Kepco: http://www.kepcopower.com/ The BOP series are 4-quadrant supplies. The EL series are electronic loads specifically.

Comment: @The Photon, Not sure to be honest. For the sake of discussion, lets say that it can. Then the fixed resistance should be choosen to maintain a safe operating voltage for the current sink.

Example: 60V current source, to maintain 7A's of current through the loop a 4 Ohm resistor will operate the current source in the middle of its operating voltage range of around 28V. If you chose an 8 Ohm resistor for example, then you'll be operating really close to the supply's limits (7A * 8 Ohms = 56V-5=51V). Also the fixed resistor limit in cause the supply goes to 0V, so at least 5V/7A = 1 Ohm minimum

Comment: How are you connecting the resistor? In series between the two supplies or in parallel between the common +5 V point and ground? A schematic would help clarify what you're proposing?

Comment: @The Photon added drawing

Comment: Assuming only one (or none) of the supplies ties its negative terminal to earth ground, what you drew will not immediately blow up. I haven't thought through all the failure modes, though.  Also be aware the resistor is dissipating 200 W. You will want to think carefully about what kind of resistors to use and how to heat-sink them. The Agilent supply will also need to have a terminal disconnect feature (or you need to add a switch) to be able to turn the system off (I=0) programatically.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah the Agilent supply is isolated from earth ground, and also the DC to DC converter is also. 

I'm curious, on the theory of why it would blow up if they both had an earth ground? I'm trying to find theory on using electronic loads like this also.

The Power resistor is two 150Watt 8 Ohm resistors tied in parallel to get the 4 Ohm with 300 Watt heat dissipation. I'm hoping the heat sink is big enough

Comment: For example, if both of them had their (-) terminal tied to ground, the Agilent supply would be short circuited. It probably wouldn't literally blow up, but it'd probably be shut down by their protection circuits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most power supplies do not have "current sinking" capability.

When discussing this, we talk about the four quadrants of the I-V space:

[image]

Where the response curve of the supply is plotted with I on the x-axis and V on the y-axis. For example an ideal voltage supply would be characterised by a horizontal line at constant voltage, no matter what the current.

Most power supplies can operate only in the I quadrant. This means that current is going out of the more positive terminal of the supply. Some can also (or you can flip the leads to work in) the III quadrant. In these quadrants, the supply is delivering power to its load.

Only specially designed supplies can operate in the II and IV quadrants. These are called "4 quadrant supplies". An example of this is the BOP series supplies from [Kepco](http://www.kepcopower.com/).

There are also "electronic loads" designed to operate in the II and IV quadrants, such as the [Agilent N6063B](http://www.home.agilent.com/en/pd-1000001520:epsg:pro-pn-6063B/250-watt-dc-electronic-load?cc=US&lc=eng).

However, it's not obvious from what you said about the goals of your test that you couldn't simply connect a (or a combination of) power resistors to the supply being tested instead of spending a lot of money on an electronic load.

Comment: The electronic Load will be easier for the test because the requirements are to ramp the load from minimum load all the way up to 100% load in 15 steps. The Agilent supply or any electronic load would be smoother and easier to control than switching in and out power resistors.